# Edit PHP query result in textarea with word count option

Tags: php, textarea, word-count

I have created a word count textarea in my form, with reference from your site, it works fine. I'm trying to edit the data from my mysql db in below code, i can get the data in textarea, but word count is not working.

Anybody help me?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#12").on('keyup', function() {
        var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
        if (words > 300) {
            // Split the string on first 300 words and rejoin on spaces
            var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 300).join(" ");
            // Add a space at the end to keep new typing making new words
            $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
        }
        else {
            $('#display_count_12').text(words);
            $('#word_left_12').text(300-words);
        }
    });
 });
```

```html
<textarea name="f12" id="12" style="width:753px; height:80px;"><?php echo $f12;?></textarea><br>
<span style="font-size:14px"> &nbsp; Total word count: <span id="display_count_12">0</span> words. Words left: <span id="word_left_12" style="font-size:14px;color:red">300</span></span>
```

Comment: is a pure numeric id allowed?

Answer (score 0):

It's because the word count is only updating when you type something in your textarea.
So you have to initiate it on page load.

Replace your js with that.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(function(){
        let words = $('#12').val().match(/\S+/g).length;
        $('#display_count_12').text(words);
        $('#word_left_12').text(300 - words);
    });

    $("#12").on('keyup', function() {
        var words = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
        if (words > 300) {
            // Split the string on first 300 words and rejoin on spaces
            var trimmed = $(this).val().split(/\s+/, 300).join(" ");
            // Add a space at the end to keep new typing making new words
            $(this).val(trimmed + " ");
        }
        else {
            $('#display_count_12').text(words);
            $('#word_left_12').text(300-words);
        }
    });

 });
```